# hiding react native webview bottom status bar

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a webview in React Native that has a text input box.  When I focus on the text input box, a Safari status bar component shows up at the bottom of the view.  Is there any way to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to share your code on https://snack.expo.io/? So we can try out what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a keyboardType prop
. A keyboardType 
Determines which keyboard to open, e.g.numeric.

The following values work across platforms:

```
default
number-pad
decimal-pad
numeric
email-address
phone-pad
```

iOS Only

The following values work on iOS only:

```
ascii-capable
numbers-and-punctuation
url
name-phone-pad
twitter
web-search
```

try using a different keyboardType and check the difference.

Also, I'm not sure but you can try setting the backgroundColor of the WebView to transparent and the "border" won't be rendered.